# Help determining pinout for communications port

Tags: serial-communication

I have a Panasonic air conditioner that has a header on the mainboard that various optional (expensive) addon communications modules can connect into eg wifi

The unit is a Panasonic Split system from the CU/CSZ20TKR range (however this connector is common across many of the panasonic series)

I am wanting to see if I can connect to this port and control it over serial or similar once I determine what protocol it is using. RS232?, RS485?
I have been trying to determine what protocol this port uses to communicate with the addon modules that can be plugged into it and what the correct connections are. Once I have determined the correct pins and protocol I should be able to write a script that will do the communication.

I have done some research and probing with multimeter (I don't have an oscilloscope currently) and located a circuit diagram for the header on the mainboard,

What i have determined so far:

- Pin 1 5v
- Pin 2 5v
- Pin 3 5v
- Pin 4 12v
- Pin 5 Gnd

[image: Circuit diagram of the port]

Some of the modules available to plug into this port are:

- CZ-TACG1 Wifi kit: http://www.panasonic.hk/usm.ashx/e/7zt1rwYXAiWEX1X3Hkyy9Naxy7NSnBFA89YBELQe-2L0J2RMcxQSCsgXytHbtm7ZBFLpQZ8phzb451XTOV_fX3-xb7Vrxt1ft7KR-ODzZh6hNYcPgXEggCffw1CXZUluSh5e~UC~0Hc00GxCOL1ctdmAe6NNFvzxYL30cW-4zk8o/CZ-TACG1-WiFi-adapter-users-maunal.pdf
- IntesisBox PA-AC-BAC-1: https://www.intesisbox.com/intesis/product/media/intesisbox_pa-ac-bac-1_installation_manual_en.pdf?v=2.1
- Panasonic PAW-SERVER-PKEA -
  https://www.panasonicproclub.com/uploads/IE/catalogues/II_PAW-SERVER_PKEA_v44_EN_2013.pdf

Comment: You'd have a lot more luck if you had one of the options and could plug it in while watching with a scope or a cheap logic analyzer (be mindful of course of making any electrical connection to line powered appliances - you don't know that the low voltage internals are not riding on lethal mains voltage!). The two signals with the 10K pullups could be an I2C bus but the PAW-SERVER doc implies they are a distinct transmit and receive.  Maybe you'll be lucky and those, or the one with no components will see some "is anything there" polling during startup.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have a logic analyzer on order. It would be great if I could get one of the devices, but they are out of my budget for now.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, I have received the cheap logic analyzer and attached to the 3 5v lines. There does appear to be something being output when the device is powered on and also continuously while the device is on and in standby https://i.imgur.com/Pmi1rC3.png

Answer (score 1):

I think the pinout is the following according to Server Back-Up PC Board manual:

[image]